# Chart with colour density for standard deviation

Tags: r

Is it possible to draw a line chart with the standard deviation around the line shown as a colour density, so for example 1 stdev would be the same but a deeper colour that 2stdev?

Comment: This is what I was looking for:http://www.r-bloggers.com/visually-weighted-regression-in-r-a-la-solomon-hsiang/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_smooth.html), the `geom_smooth` layer can do what you're looking for.

See the second example on the page I linked.  You would just need to either add multiple layers or a factor and use the `fill` aesthetic to color them.